# Cell Look Up In Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am working IN excel and am looking for an equation/formula to put inside one of the cells.

I have a column and there are 10 rows in that column. Periodically it will be updated and a user may add to that cell. So my range is **`A1:A10`**.

What I am trying to do is get the cell that has a value in it for that range..

For example the column looks like this:

```
Author1
Author2
Author3
Author4
Author5
Author6
(blank cell)
(blank cell)
(blank cell)
(blank cell)
```

I want to get the last value in that range, so the value in the new cell would be `Author6`. How can I do this?

### EDIT

I came up with this but excel throws an error stating:

```
The specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more levels of nesting than are allowed in the current file format.
```

I came up with this formula and it seems to be working fine if I get rid of some of the values being checked..

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A10)),A10,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A9)),A9,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A8)),A8,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A7)),A7,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A6)),A6,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A5)),A5,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A4)),A4,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),A3,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),A2,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),A1,C3))))))
```

Does anyone know how I can improve this formula/make it shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the simplest formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10, COUNTA($A$1:$A$10), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,MAX(IF(A1:A10<>"",ROW(A1:A10))))
```

Enter as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: This seems to return `0`.. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It works just fine for me.  If entered properly, the formula will appear surrounded by {...}.